# What is the grammar behind 見よ?

Tags: grammar

I just started reading a Japanese version of the New Testament when I encountered this.  The English has it as "Behold", but 見よ doesn't seem to be a command form that I am familiar with.  Is this something specific to 見る?

Answer (score 2):

見よ is an older command conjugation of 見る (see http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1239056022 if you can read it).

Basically, [見]{み} is  the masu stem of 見る -- used 見ます and 見ない. Drop the part after the stem and adding よ makes it a type of command.

見ろ is of course also a type of command.